# Language folders for Silverlight projects when building with Team Build

Tags: silverlight, msbuild

I have a Silverlight 4 project in my solution. When I automate the compilation of the Silverlight project in Team Build, I get in my output folder a long list of folders that have the Silverlight translations in it.

These folders are not present in a local build (compile from Visual Studio), and I don't want them since I am targeting only one language. I have not found a setting to specify to not get these folders, and even better specify the languages I want to support.

Does anybody know how to get rid of these folders, without adding a task to the build to remove the folders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight resource dll build prevention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562227/silverlight-resource-dll-build-prevention)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Windows Explorer. Go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client.
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\ if you're running 64-bit Windows). In that location, you will see a bunch of language/culture folders.

- Create a new folder. I named mine "Unused Cultures."
- Move all the culture folders that you do not want to use to the the
  new folder. Be sure NOT to move the "Design" folder, which appears in the middle of the culture folders in the folder list.
- In your project, delete the contents of the Bin, Release, etc. folders. Rebuild.
- When you want to add support for another culture, just move the one you want
  back to the original location.
- Whenever you get an update to the Silverlight SDK, you will probably have to do this again.